# How to increase performance when inserting more than 40k+ rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE new_details_staging 
(
    e_id         NUMBER(10),
    e_name       VARCHAR2(30),
    portal_desc  VARCHAR2(50),
    risk_dec     VARCHAR2(50),
    CONSTRAINT pk_new_details_staging PRIMARY KEY (e_id)
);

INSERT INTO new_details_staging 
VALUES (11, 'A', 'AA', 'High');

INSERT INTO new_details_staging 
VALUES (22, 'B', 'BB', 'Low');

CREATE TABLE lookup_ref 
(
    ref_id       NUMBER(10),
    ref_typ      VARCHAR2(30),
    ref_typ_desc VARCHAR2(20),
    CONSTRAINT pk_lookup_ref PRIMARY KEY (ref_id)
);

INSERT INTO lookup_ref 
VALUES (181, 'portal', 'AA');

INSERT INTO lookup_ref 
VALUES (182, 'portal', 'BB');

INSERT INTO lookup_ref 
VALUES (183, 'risk', 'High');

INSERT INTO lookup_ref 
VALUES (184, 'risk', 'Low');

CREATE TABLE new_details_main 
(
    e_id    NUMBER(10),
    e_name  VARCHAR2(30),
    portal  NUMBER(20),
    risk    NUMBER(20),
    CONSTRAINT pk_new_details_main PRIMARY KEY (e_id)
);

COMMIT;
```

My attempt:

```
INSERT INTO new_details_main (e_id, e_name, portal,risk)
    SELECT  
        n.e_id,
        n.e_name,
        (SELECT lr.ref_id
         FROM lookup_ref lr
         WHERE lr.ref_typ = 'portal'
           AND lr.ref_typ_desc = n.portal_desc),
        (SELECT lr.ref_id
         FROM lookup_ref lr
         WHERE lr.ref_typ = 'risk'
           AND lr.ref_typ_desc = n.risk_dec)
    FROM    
        new_details_staging n;
```

Currently, I am inserting a few records and it is giving exact results but in actuality, there are 40k+ records so I believe it will give performance issues also. Is there any way to insert the records faster because I will write a procedure for this insertion? Is there any other in which I can write an insert query inside the procedure?

Comment: If inserting 40k rows (there are no "records" in a relational database) takes longer than a second or so, then something is wrong. Either you are doing it in an exceptionally poor way, or it's actually many more than 40k rows. 40k rows to insert is NOTHING.

Comment: Are there triggers, indexes on the new table? If you run the select statement without the insert, what is the performance and execution plan of that look like?

Comment: So, `new_details_main` has a lot more records ? what about `new_details_staging`. Can you give us table counts to give us an idea ?

Comment: The insert you have looks reasonable. Is it actually slow, or are you just looking for pointers in case it is?

Comment: @mathguy Thanks for looking into this. It actually had 40k records but it is feasible to insert that many rows within seconds as Connor had shown an example with 80k rows. So, I am good with it :)

Comment: @eaolson There were no triggers to the target table. Since I have to write a procedure to insert records from the staging table to the target table. So, might be INSERT clause creates a performance issue but now I am clear that it can be done. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Hi William, I was looking for a pointer in case it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my laptop, we can scale your test easily enough

```
SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE new_details_staging
  2  (
  3      e_id         NUMBER(10),
  4      e_name       VARCHAR2(30),
  5      portal_desc  VARCHAR2(50),
  6      risk_dec     VARCHAR2(50),
  7      CONSTRAINT pk_new_details_staging PRIMARY KEY (e_id)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO new_details_staging VALUES (11, 'A', 'AA', 'High');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO new_details_staging  VALUES (22, 'B', 'BB', 'Low');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into new_details_staging
  2  select e_id*500000+rownum, e_name, portal_desc, risk_dec
  3  from new_details_staging,
  4   ( select 1 from dual connect by level <= 400000 );

800000 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE lookup_ref
  2  (
  3      ref_id       NUMBER(10),
  4      ref_typ      VARCHAR2(30),
  5      ref_typ_desc VARCHAR2(20),
  6      CONSTRAINT pk_lookup_ref PRIMARY KEY (ref_id)
  7  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO lookup_ref VALUES (181, 'portal', 'AA');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO lookup_ref VALUES (182, 'portal', 'BB');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO lookup_ref VALUES (183, 'risk', 'High');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO lookup_ref VALUES (184, 'risk', 'Low');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE new_details_main
  2  (
  3      e_id    NUMBER(10),
  4      e_name  VARCHAR2(30),
  5      portal  NUMBER(20),
  6      risk    NUMBER(20),
  7      CONSTRAINT pk_new_details_main PRIMARY KEY (e_id)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> set timing on
SQL> INSERT INTO new_details_main (e_id, e_name, portal,risk)
  2      SELECT
  3          n.e_id,
  4          n.e_name,
  5          (SELECT lr.ref_id
  6           FROM lookup_ref lr
  7           WHERE lr.ref_typ = 'portal'
  8             AND lr.ref_typ_desc = n.portal_desc),
  9          (SELECT lr.ref_id
 10           FROM lookup_ref lr
 11           WHERE lr.ref_typ = 'risk'
 12             AND lr.ref_typ_desc = n.risk_dec)
 13      FROM
 14          new_details_staging n;

800002 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.97
SQL>
SQL>
```

So around 3 seconds for 800,000 rows.  I think you'll be fine :-)

If the lookups are always true and key preserved, you might get some benefit converting to a join, eg

```
SQL> set timing on
SQL> INSERT INTO new_details_main (e_id, e_name, portal,risk)
  2      SELECT
  3          n.e_id,
  4          n.e_name,
  5          lr.ref_id,
  6          lr1.ref_id
  7      FROM
  8          new_details_staging n,
  9          lookup_ref lr,
 10          lookup_ref lr1
 11  where lr.ref_typ = 'portal'
 12  AND lr.ref_typ_desc = n.portal_desc
 13  and lr1.ref_typ = 'risk'
 14  AND lr1.ref_typ_desc = n.risk_dec ;

800002 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.64
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was on the assumption that merging is much faster than the insert. But as you showed with an example that's helped me